# What is this windows button called?

Tags: windows, windows-10

On the bottom left there is a button showing the program menu. Right now, it shows an hourglass cursor for 1 second when I click on it but it doesnt open.

I am unable to research further as I am not sure what the name of that button is.

[image]

Comment: This is the "Start button", which opens the "Start menu".

Comment: The **Start button** if officially referenced here:  [See what's on the Start menu](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17195/windows-10-see-whats-on-the-menu)

Comment: Is your question really about the name, or why the behaviour?

Comment: @Dave Yes my question was about the name. With the name I could google and found the answer. Result I have to reinstall some stuff and now is working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is referred to as the 'start button' or 'start menu'. On the keyboard it is usually known as the 'windows key' or 'windows logo key'.

As an aside, the problem with the "windows key" is it causes confusion with a windows license key.

However, as to why it doesn't 'work' when clicked isn't easy.

First off, verify that clicking in icons on the desktop selects them. Then try clicking on anything in the task bar to verify that. Also, if possible, see if touching works.

Event viewer may help.

If you have any keyboard mapping, it may be causing the issue you describe

It is unlikely to be a driver issue, but it may be worth while investigating.